# How to pass extra data after validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

After validation I want to pass some extra data to view. However, I can't send it.

My controller is like,

```php
public function test()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        request()->all(), 
        [ 'ziptest' => 'regex:/^([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})$/']
    );

    $errors = $validator->errors();

    if($errors->any()) {
        return back()
            ->withErrors($errors)
            ->withTitle('Data From Controller')
            ->withInput();
    }

    return 'success';
}
```

In my blade I want to check if the title is passed or not. So in my blade view I have

```php
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif

@if(isset($title))
    <p>{{ $title }}</p>
@endif
```

However, the error portion is displaying properly. But not the title. Why is it not working?

I also tried sending the title in this way.

```php
return back()->withErrors($errors)
    ->with('title','Data From Controller')
    ->withInput();
```

It is also not working.

I searched in the SO and found several similar questions regarding passing data from controller to view. However, my situation is a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are redirecting back to the previous location. When you use `with*` for a redirect the information is *flashed to the session*, rather than made directly available to the view like it would be if you were returning a view instead.

For it to work with your example, you would have to check `session('title')` to get the flashed title from the redirect.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it. 

Just a bit more clarification. return view()->with() and return back()->with(); Both with() do not work in same way. Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly - view builds the Blade view file passing through the given data, redirect generates a HTTP redirect and places the given data into the session. Laravel automatically re-populates the view with errors from the session (see the ShareErrorsFromSession middleware in your app).

Comment: As a sidenote, `withErrors` does actually create an `$errors` variable in the redirected route but that is happening because of middleware `ShareErrorsFromSession` so that is a special case. You could presumably make your own middleware to emulate a similar behaviour for other variables

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is almost correct.

```php
return back()->withErrors($errors)
    ->with([
        'title' => 'Data From Controller'
    ])
    ->withInput();
```

note the array notation

Comment: Sorry, the problem is still there. No 'title' in blade page.

Answer (score 0):

use here `array_merge` method

```
    $errors = $validator->errors();

    if($errors->any()) {
      $newErrors = array_merge($errors->toArray(),['title' => 'Data From Controller']);  
      return back()
            ->withErrors($newErrors)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: It is returning the data but as an error. Is it possible to send the data as a normal variable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried after validation hook but it will return data as in error bag

```
 $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $validator->errors()->add('someField', 'Somedata');
 });
```

And i'm wondering from where are you calling view because i saw your `test()` method do only validation part, with you're view you can pass data with it but with validation i think as in error bag you can send data to view.

Comment: Why should I return the data inside error bag? It is not an errror. I am not calling view from here. Only I am doing validation.

Comment: Look you've alot of dirty options like session and cookies otherwise pass data with view where ever you're calling your view from.